# First chance NoViableAltException slows down debugging

Tags: c#, antlr

We use antlr for a hierarchy of data points, which can be calculated from each other, where the calculation is expressed by a formula.
Say we have base data points a1 and a2, which come from external measurement systems.
Then we can define a data point b to be calculated as sum from a1 and a2 by the formula 
"a1 + a2".

Everything works so far, but the problem is, that antlr seems to backtrack wrong branches while parsing by throwing, catching and re-throwing NoViableAltException.

We use the C# port of Antlr from Sam Harwell and use it with C#, and debug in VStudio 2012.
Visual Studio catches and displays first chance exceptions, and this is a rather slow process.
Even if in the debugger window one opts to not display first chance exceptions, they still are caught and slow down the debugger.

As there are hundreds of data points which are defined by formulas, these first chance exceptions make debugging very very slow.

My question is: Is there a way to improve the grammar in order to reduce the number of first chance NoViableAltException?

Or would it make sense to change the antlr code, to implement backtracking by return value instead of throwing / catching NoViableAltException?

Comment: I'm not an antlr user but do these exceptions occur in your code or in the library?

Comment: They occur in the library and the code which is auto-generated by antlr from my grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how ANTLR 3 behaves with the `backtrack=true` option, because I personally never used that construct in production.

- If you are able, you should consider [updating to ANTLR 4](https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs), which does not require resorting to backtracking for long lookahead sequences (in fact, there is no `backtrack` option in ANTLR 4).
- Otherwise, you should update your grammar to remove the `backtrack=true` option while successfully parsing your inputs. This will dramatically improve the performance of your parser even outside the debugger.

The `backtrack=true` option should be treated as an experimental option only. Its impact on production code is heavy and often leads to unpredictable and/or unexplainable behavior.

Comment: I didn't set the backtrack=true option explicitly. May be I did use the term backtracking incorrectly. Anyway there are many first chance NoViableAltException thrown during the parsing process. Is this regular behavior of antlr or is something wrong with the grammar?

Comment: It means the grammar is not a correct representation of your input, or vice versa. If you correct the grammar or syntax error it will stop throwing exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. I always thought that this exception was a regular mechanism in the parsing process, and hence did not check, if it was related to a certain part of the input expression.

Comment: Well, now I re-checked and found that it was related to appending EOF (0xffff) to the input. I thought it would be necessary for the parser to know were to stop. I also have EOF in my grammar, but not in the lexer file as it is automatically added by antlr in the generated lexer code. It is in the grammar as some kind of leftover from antlr2. Anyway, I stopped appending EOF and now there are no exceptions any more. Thanks a lot.